# Visual Studio 2015 - Minimum Rebuild when Start Debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

My project has 15 projects and 1 solution file

If my source code has not been modified, Visual Studio prompts me if I want to build the 15 project files?

There is a box to say not to display it again, I'm not sure why Visual Studio thinks the code is out of date?

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

> If my source code has not been modified, Visual Studio prompts me if I
> want to build the 15 project files?

No. If your code has not been changed, it will always show `up-to-date`, not build. VS has the feature of [incremental build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-incrementally?view=vs-2019).

**Note**: you should click **Build** button rather than **Rebuild**. **Rebuild** will execute clean and then build, so it will always execute the whole build process.

**Once** you do not modify the resource files, MSBuild will detect that the project has not changed and does not need to be built again, turns out to `up-to-date`.

**Therefore**, under normal circumstances, MSBuild will not build again without changing the project.

> There is a box to say not to display it again, I'm not sure why Visual
> Studio thinks the code is out of date?

In fact, it should not happen.

If you have not made any changes to the project but the build still displays `out-of-date`, you have to check the diagnostic build log and find it out.

Enter **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run**--> set **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Diagnostic` . And then build your project to find the cause out.

[image]

Maybe you have set **Copy To Output Directories** of some files to `Copy always` or you have lost the files for inputs and ouputs, .... so on.